# Как эмулировать прокрутку элемента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходимо чтобы при попытке прокрутки одного элемента прокручивался другой. Причём, способ c `onWheel`+`scrollTop` не подходит, так как прокрутка получается резкой, неестественной. И никакой `behavior: smooth` это не исправляет (да, прокрутка становится плавной, но ещё менее естественной). Неужели нельзя никак "перенаправить" событие..?

Простейший пример:

```js
const myWheel = (e) => {
  document.getElementById('elem2').scrollTop += e.deltaY
  document.getElementById('elem3').scrollTop += e.deltaY
}
document.getElementById('elem1').addEventListener("wheel", myWheel)
```

```css
.elems {
  display: flex;
}
.elems > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#elem3 {scroll-behavior: smooth}
```

```html
<div class='elems'>
  <div id='elem1' style='background: pink'>
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
  </div>
  <div id='elem2' style='background: lightblue'>
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
  </div>
  <div id='elem3' style='background: lightgreen'>
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый элемент не прокручивается, при скролле над ним прокручиваются два другие:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.elems');

var pos, skip, timer

reset();

function reset() {
  skip = true
  pos = container.scrollTop = 500;
  skip = false
}

container.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  if (skip || event.target !== container) return

  var st = container.scrollTop, diff = st - pos
  pos = st;

  var divs = container.children, i = 1, sts = Array(i);

  for (var q=i; q<divs.length; ++q) {
    sts.push(divs[q].scrollTop + diff);
  }

  for (var q=i; q<divs.length; ++q) {
    divs[q].scrollTop = sts[q];
  }
  
  clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = setTimeout(reset, 1000)
});
```

```css
main {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.elems {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.elems > div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.elems > div:first-child {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.elems::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class='elems'>
    <div id='elem1' style='background: pink'>
      a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
      a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    </div>
    <div id='elem2' style='background: lightblue'>
      a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
      a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    </div>
    <div id='elem3' style='background: lightgreen'>
      a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
      a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    </div>
  </div>
<main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы прокрутка оставалась плавной, надо присваивать scrollTop для всех элементов кроме того, который скроллит пользователь. И надо использовать нормальное событие `scroll`, а не какие-то мышиные аналоги. В IE останется [проблема с синхронизацией во время скролла](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760433/178988), в Chrome всё будет идеально, в FF достаточно хорошо. Улцчшить не удалось.

```js
var last = 0;

document.body.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  var st = event.target.scrollTop;
  
  if (st !== last) {
    last = st;
    
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    
    for (var q=0; q<divs.length; ++q) {
      if (divs[q] !== event.target) {
        divs[q].scrollTop = st;
      }
    }
  }
}, true);
```

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  direction: ltr;
}

div:first-child {
  direction: rtl;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 10000px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0, white 29px, black 30px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: `надо использовать нормальное событие scroll, а не какие-то мышиные аналоги` в этом вся и проблема, ведь в вопросе написано именно "перенаправить", а не "скопировать". То есть, как я уже писал в комментариях, `elem1 прокручиваться не должен, в примере так сделано для наглядности сравнения.`

Comment: @LRSM, тогда лучше перевесить скролл на контейнер. Ну и как совсем костыль, можно прикрутить [вот такой финт с transform](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550320/178988). И ещё [его вариация](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951253/178988).

Comment: `можно прикрутить вот такой финт с transform` - как, когда элемент, над которым происходит прокрутка, не должен прокручиваться, а через onWheel прокрутка другого получается изначально резкой?

Comment: @LRSM, готово .

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю все ваши попытки обречены на провал, так как существуют браузеры в которых реализован [асинхронный скроллинг](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects), и любые попытки идеально синхронизировать скролинг двух различных элементов посредством событийной модели будут неудачны.

Если нужно синхронизировать именно позицию ползунка прокрутки, то взгляните на решение ниже. Тем не менее учтите, в браузерах с асинхронным скроллингом данное решение будет работать рывками.

```js
var el1 = document.getElementById('elem1'),
    el2 = document.getElementById('elem2'),
    el3 = document.getElementById('elem3');

const onScroll = (e) => {
  el2.scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
  el3.scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop;
};

el1.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
```

```css
.elems {
  display: flex;
}
.elems > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#elem3 {
/*  scroll-behavior: smooth */
}
```

```html
<div class='elems'>
  <div id='elem1' style='background: pink'>
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
  </div>
  <div id='elem2' style='background: lightblue'>
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
  </div>
  <div id='elem3' style='background: lightgreen'>
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
    a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>k
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `синхронизировать именно позицию ползунка прокрутки` это понятно, но elem1 прокручиваться не должен, в примере так сделано для наглядности сравнения.

Comment: `все ваши попытки обречены на провал` - тогда остаётся вариант вручную написать логику для анимации `scrollTop += e.deltaY`, хотя бы приблизно. Только как? Через _for-settimeout_ глупо надеяться что-то хорошее получить...

Comment: глупо не глупо - важно не это... подумайте как вы собираетесь в идеале синхронизировать между собой огромную пачку асинхронных событий.